# Show that the integral equals zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The question asks to show that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos (t)}[\cos(t)\sin(\sin (t))-\sin (t)\cos(\sin (t))]dt = 0 $$

I have managed through Euler's formula for both $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ to derive 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2i} e^{-it}(e^{e^{it}}-e^{e^{-it}+2it})dt $$

I did this all through symbolic manipulation in Mathematica and I'm sure I haven't input anything incorrectly.

I am confused on how to proceed from this point or if there is another route to the solution that I missed.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says that your integral is approx. 6.70461

Comment: @elidiot, please share a link to the wolframalpha output.

Comment: see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ecos(t)%5Bcos(t)%E2%88%97sin(sin(t))%E2%88%92sin(t)%E2%88%97cos(sin(t))%5Ddt++from+0+to+2*pi) vs. [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(e%5Ecos(t))%5Bcos(t)%E2%88%97sin(sin(t))%E2%88%92sin(t)%E2%88%97cos(sin(t))%5Ddt++from+0+to+2*pi)

Answer (score 3):

By periodicity the integral is same as the integral from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$. The integrand is an odd function so the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a change of variables. Let $u=2\pi - x$ and  note that

$$\sin(2\pi-u) = \sin(2\pi)\cos(u)-\cos(2\pi)\sin(u) = -\sin(u)$$

and

$$\cos(2\pi-u) = \cos(2\pi)\cos(u)+\sin(2\pi)\sin(u) = \cos(u)$$

You will find that you get the same integral, but with an overall minus sign. The only real number which satisfies $I=-I$ is $I=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Making the change $t\to \tau-\pi$ we have

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos(t)}\left(\cos(t)\sin(\sin(t))-\sin(t)\cos(\sin(t))\right)dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin (\tau +\sin (\tau )) e^{-\cos (\tau )}d\tau = 0
$$